# SAS: Extract ID's separated by dashes from text string

Tags: sas, delimiter

I have a dataset that has one concatenated text field. I am trying to break it into three text columns in SAS 9.4.

```
Obs Var1
1   MAY12-KANSAS-ABCD6194-XY7199-BRULE
2   JAN32-OHIO-BZ5752-GARY
```

My output for observation 1 should look like this:

```
Obs   Date   State   ID
1     MAY12  KANSAS  ABCD6194-XY7199-BRULE
```

Here's what I have, which works for the Date and State.  However, I can't get the third part (ID) to ignore the delimiter:

```
data have;
   input Var1 &$64.;
   cards;
MAY12-KANSAS-ABCD6194-XY7199-BRULE
JAN32-OHIO-BZ5752-GARY
;
run;
data need;
   length id $16;
   set have;
   date = scan(var1,1,'-','o');
   state = scan(var1,2,'-','o');
   id = scan(var1,3,'-','');
run;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another different approach to get a multi-delimiter-containing word is to use [`call scan`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/67398/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0ecxfx00bn8i4n1vhh8up24ha6x.htm).  It will tell you the position (and length, which we ignore) of the nth word (and can be forwards OR backwards, so this gives you some ability to search in the middle of the string).

Implemented for this particular case it's very simple:

```
data want;
  set have;
  length 
    date $5
    state $20
    id $50
  ;
  date = scan(var1,1);
  state= scan(var1,2);
  call scan(var1,3,position,length);
  id = substr(var1,position);
run;
```

`position` and `length` are variables that `call scan` populates with values which we can then use.  (We could have done date and state that way also, but it's more work than using the function.)

Answer (score 2):

Regular Expression maybe an option

The detailed documenation can be found here: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/67398/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0r8h2fa8djqf1n1cnenrvm573br.htm

I will suggest you to start with this paper: http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi29/265-29.pdf

Direct explantation on the code may even confuse you worse if you have never touched those PRX functions.

```
data have;
    input Var1 &$64.;
    cards;
MAY12-KANSAS-ABCD6194-XY7199-BRULE
JAN32-OHIO-BZ5752-GARY
;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    date=scan(var1,1);
    state=scan(var1,2);
    id=prxchange('s/^\w+-\w+-//',1,var1);
run;
```

Or as a simple fix to your existing code:

```
data want;
    set have;
    date=scan(var1,1);
    state=scan(var1,2);
/*  id=prxchange('s/^\w+-\w+-//',1,var1);*/
    id=substr(var1,length(cats(date,state))+3);
run;
```

The expression started by length function will give the start point where to extract your string of interest. Length + Cats function will give the total length of date and state, +3 is offset '-'.

Comment: Thanks for the help here.  I'm not familiar with the PRXCHANGE function so I am having difficulty manipulating it in my code.  The code you suggested gives me "ABCD6194-XY7199-" instead of "ABCD6194-XY7199-BRULE".  How would I alter the function to give me that last "BRULE" piece of the string?

Comment: @HaikuoBian  You may want to explain the logic within the regular expression, ie. explain the patterns it is searching for, to help Ryan understand how it works.

Comment: It maybe a length thing. Add a length statement at the beginning of the data step: data want; set have; length id $ 100; .... /*large enough to hold the your longest possible ID*/

Comment: @HaikuoBian StackOverflow prefers "Teach a man to fish" approach - please _always_ explain what your code is doing and what the approach is, preferentially even over providing any code at all.

Comment: Haikuo - your solution actually worked... the problem was on my end: i had set the length of id at 16 which is why it was cutting the last few characters off.  Once I changed the length to 40, your solution gave me exactly what I needed.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Ryan, in response with the sentiments from Rober and Joe. Comments have been just added.

Comment: @HaikuoBian Thanks for adding that.  Please add direct explanation for the first part - something simple is sufficient like "Here we remove the first two pieces with PRX and the rest is the ID".  It's less important to link to the function doc than to simply explain the reasoning behind what you're doing.  What you did in the second paragraph is perfect (though I would not use italics like that, it's a bit harder to read).

Comment: @Joe Being new to this forum, have no clue how italics occured. I did the same thing as put them into the commenting braket /*  */. Thank you for helping out.

Comment: @HaikuoBian We use Markdown here - similar to R for example. Just put your explanation if it's a paragraph in plain text. If you want comments like I did I would make them line comments, but that's just for little notes mostly.

Answer (score 1):

`_INFILE_ Magic` is the search term for this.  Basically, we use the `_infile_` automatic variable (which contains the line currently being read in from the input file) to take advantage of the easy syntax for inputting.

```
*Create a dataset with your data;
data have;
  length var1 $100;
  input var1 $;
datalines;
MAY12-KANSAS-ABCD6194-XY7199-BRULE
JAN32-OHIO-BZ5752-GARY
;;;;
run;

data want;
  infile cards dlm='-';  *cards=datalines=in-line data, just used to get something blank to pretend to read from;
  length
    date $5
    state $20
    id $50
  ;                 *set up lengths for your variables;
  set have;         *Now read in your dataset;
  input @1 @@;      *Start the input pointer at the beginning of the imaginary line and do not advance lines ever (since we have no lines!);
  _infile_=var1;    *Assign the contents of var1 to _infile_, so now we have a line;
  input
    date $
    state $
    id $ & @@
    ;               *Input using normal input techniques.  & tells it to read the rest of that line into the id variable (even the dashes), and @@ says stay on this line still (since we have more rows).
  cards;

run;                *Note we do not really have any cards/datalines.;
```

Note this only works because your embedded delimiters occur at the end of the line.  If they were in the middle of the line, this approach would not work and you would have to use a different approach (such as a regular expression, or telling whomever gave you a file formatted in this way to give it to you in a more useful fashion, ie, not using a delimiter that also is in the data).

Answer (score 1):

Use tranwrd to drop date and state.

```
data want;
  set have;
  length 
    date $5
    state $20
    id $50
  ;
  date = scan(var1,1);
  state= scan(var1,2);
  id= tranwrd(var1,cats(date,'-',state,'-'),'');
run;
```